# Partitions on Ubuntu 20.04 server for DellPower3dg3 R6515

Tags: partitioning, raid

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu but please help me with the following issue:

I need to create 12 partitions as follows:

[image: Partitions]

The scheme to create these ones on the disk is RAID 1 and it was already setup. I'm using this setup for the disk:

[image: Raid1]

[image: Disk Config]

But when all the partitions have been created:

[Partitions Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5dud.png)

Proceed to select "Done" everything seems to be well but after type, the hostname, user, and password and going to the next stage only appear an error:

[image: Error]

And that's all an error is showing up and the installer is restarted

Please advise regarding this issue or even what I'm doing wrong?

Really appreciated all your support,
Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when you select “View Full Report”? I’m also not seeing a need to create 12 partitions, but maybe 7 

Comment: The full report is a thousands of words and if you can gave a clue about how to read that report of something else would be appreciate. Anyway if I only can create the 7 partitions that you said after the installation, can I create that partitions and mount them? If so could you please help me about how to to that? Thanks a lot

Comment: @BlackRabbit We don't really mind that much reading a bunch of lines. Just add it to pastebin